# How to ensure that a python function generates its output based only on its input?

Tags: python, database, functional-programming, filesystems, httpwebrequest

To generate an output a function usually uses only values of its arguments. However, there are also cases in which function, to generate its output, reads something from a file system or from a database or from the web. I would like to have a simple and reliable way to ensure that something like that does not happen.

One way that I see is to create a white-list of python libraries that can be used to read from file system, database or web. But if it is the way to go, where can I get this (potentially huge) list. Moreover, I do not want to disable the whole library just because it can be used to read from the file system. For example I want users to be able to use pandas library (to store and manipulate tabular data). I just do not want them to be able to use this library to read data from the file system.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: Back up a step. *Why* do you want to prevent someone from reading from an external source?

Comment: There are many reasons. First of all, I want to be sure that in future the function will generate the same output as today. Second, in general, I think it is an "ugly" solution when a function somewhere reads something. It should see only what it explicitly receives as input. If something should be read from a file or database it should be read outside of the function and passed to the function as one of its inputs.

Comment: So you want to use code you don't trust?

Comment: Who are you trying to protect this function from? Couldn't whoever is going to change the function to read from disk also change your white-list?

Comment: It sounds like maybe you want a sandboxed version of Python. There have been a few failed attempts at implementing this (like [`pysandbox`](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2013-November/130132.html)). [PyPy has support for it](http://pypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sandbox.html), but I'm not aware of anything else that's actually secure.

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski, yes. One can put it this way. I want to use code that I do not trust. I do not care what it does until it does not read from (or write to) some "external sources" (file system, database, web).

Comment: You might want to look into Linux containers (and Docker), in case you're using Linux. Sandboxing is something which is usually best left to the operating system.

Comment: Perhaps you need to think of using a language which supports pure functional programming? 
python seems to be the wrong tool to attempt something like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to this is *no*. What you are looking for is a function that tests for `functional purity`. But, as demonstrated in this code, there's no way to guarantee that no side effects are actually being called.

```sh
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def __add__(self, y):
        print("HAHAHA evil side effects here...")
        # proceed to read a file and do stuff
        return self

# this looks pure...
def f(x): return x + 1

# but really...
>>> f(Foo(1))
HAHAHA evil side effects here...
```

Because of the comprehensive way objects can redefine their behavior (field access, calling, operator overloading etc.), you can always pass an input that makes a pure function impure. Therefore the only pure functions are those that literally do nothing with their arguments... a class of functions that is generally less useful.

Of course, if you can specify other restrictions, this becomes easier.

Comment: In your example "evil effects" happen because the user of the function did something "bad" (the user called a "good" function with a "bad" argument). In my case, I am the user of the function. So, I will not call the functions in a "bad" way. I just need to be sure that the functions that I user are not "bad".

Comment: @Roman: Your requirements were much stronger originally. You wrote: "I want users to be able to... I just do not want them to be able to use this library to read data from the file system." and now you are writing "I will not call the functions in a bad way." That seems unusual. You believe the user, but not believe the installed software?

Answer (score 4):

Your required restrictions can be broken even if you remove all modules and all functions. The code can get **access to files**, if it can use attributes of an arbitrary simple object, e.g. of number zero.

```
(0).__class__.__base__.__subclasses__()[40]('/etc/pas'+'swd')
```

The index `40` is individual and very typical for Python 2.7, but the index of subclass `<type 'file'>` can be easily found:

```
[x for x in (1).__class__.__base__.__subclasses__()if'fi'+'le'in'%s'%x][0](
 '/etc/pas'+'swd')
```

Any combination of white list and blacklist is either insecure and/or too restrictive.
The **[pypy sandbox](http://pypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sandbox.html)** is robust by the principle without compromise:

> ... This subprocess can run arbitrary untrusted Python code, but all
>   its input/output is serialized to a stdin/stdout pipe instead of being
>   directly performed. The outer process reads the pipe and decides which
>   commands are allowed or not (sandboxing), or even reinterprets them
>   differently...

Also a solution based on **[seccomp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seccomp)** kernel feature can be secure enough. ([blog](http://pythonsweetness.tumblr.com/post/65442885019/secure-low-overhead-eval-sandbox-in-80-lines-of-python))

---

> I want to be sure that in future the function will generate the same
>   output as today.

It is easy to write a function that has **hard reproducible results** and it can not be easily prevented:

```
class A(object):
    "This can be any very simple class"
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.x)

def strange_function():
    # You get a different result probably everytimes.
    return list(set(A(i) for i in range(20)))

>>> strange_function()
[1, 18, 12, 5, 16, 15, 8, 2, 14, 0, 6, 19, 13, 11, 10, 9, 17, 3, 7, 4]
>>> strange_function()
[0, 9, 14, 3, 17, 5, 6, 11, 8, 1, 15, 7, 12, 13, 2, 10, 16, 4, 19, 18]
```

... even if you remove everythng that depends on time, random number generator, order based on hash function etc., it is also easy to write a function that sometimes exceeds available memory or timeout limit and sometimes gives a result.

---

*EDIT:*
Roman, you wrote recently that you are sure you can believe the user. Then a realistic solution exists. It is to verify the input to and output from a function by recording it to a file and verifing it on a virtual machine running a remote [IPython notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html) (nice short tutorial video, support for remote computing out of box, restart of the backend service by web document menu from the browser in one second, without loss of data (input/output) in the notebook (html document) because it is created dynamically step by step by our activity triggering the javascript that calls the remote backend).

You need not be interested in internal calls, only the global input and output, until you find a difference. The virtual machine should be able to verify the results independently and reproducible. Configure the firewall that the machine accepts connections from you, but can not initiate an outgoing connection. Configure the filesystem that no data can be saved by the current user and therefore they are not present, except software components. Disable database services. Verify the results input/output in a random order or start two IPython notebook services on different ports and select a random backend for every command line on the notebook, or restart the backend process frequently before anything important. If you find a difference, debug your code and fix it.

You can automate it without "notebook" finally only with IPython remote computing after you don't need interactivity.

Comment: It should be noted that you can also get random numbers from the randomized memory address of an object. `class A:pass;str(A)`

Answer (score 4):

What you want is called sandboxing or restricted Python.

Both are mostly dead.

The closest to functional today is http://pypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sandbox.html note however that newest build is actually 3 years old.